# How to label sentiment using NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, stanford-nlp

I am trying to find the sentiment of tweets using a NLP package.

Here is an example of a tweet:

```
@SouthwestAir Fastest response all day. Hour on the phone: never got off
hold. Hour in line: never got to the Flight Booking Problems desk.
```

Here, NLP labels sentiment based on sentence. So, this tweet has three sentences with full-stops. Hence NLP gives me three different sentiment labels for each sentence of tweet. Now, how can I label entire tweet has positive, negative or neutral?

```
Neutral    @SouthwestAir Fastest response all day.
Negative    Hour on the phone: never got off hold.
Negative    Hour in line: never got to the Flight Booking Problems desk.
```

Comment: Please summarize what other NLP & sentiment analysis related posts you have read and how they don't answer your specific question... you will get more replies if you have shown due diligence in seeking an answer.

Comment: This is one of the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853905/how-to-declare-a-tweet-as-negative-or-neutral-by-using-standford-nlp

Answer (score 1):

This should have been a comment but I do not have the reputation.

There are multiple ways:

1. Simplest Approach - Use textblob to find polarity and add the polarity of all sentences. If the overall polarity of tweet is greater than 0 , then it's positive and if less than zero , you can label it as negative
2. Use of lexicons-
   One can use MQPA lexicon , to find the presence of negative and positive words and similarly , you can compute the overall polarity. [MPQA lexicon](http://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/lexicons/subj_lexicon/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is pretty old, but I just did this exact same thing less than 1 week ago, and I want to share my findings with others.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import re
import nltk 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
global str


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\data.csv')

print(df.shape)

# let's get a randome sample of data; previously tried to run some analysis and  
# system was running out of memory
df = df.fillna(0)
#df = df.sample(frac=0.1, replace=True, random_state=1)
print(df.shape)

# let's experiment with some sentiment analysis concepts
# first we need to clean up the stuff in the independent field of the DF we are workign with
df['body'] = df[['body']].astype(str)
df['review_text'] = df[['review_text']].astype(str)

df['body'] = df['body'].str.replace('\d+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.replace('\d+', '')
# get rid of special characters
df['body'] = df['body'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
# get rid fo double spaces
df['body'] = df['body'].str.replace(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.replace(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', '')
# convert all case to lower
df['body'] = df['body'].str.lower()
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.lower()

# Here we are doing some sentiment analysis, and distilling the 'review_text' field into positive, neutral, or negative, 
# based on the tone of the text in each record.  Also, we are filtering out the records that have <.2 negative score; 
# keeping only those that have >.2 negative score. This is interesting, but this can contain some non-intitive results.  
# For instance, one record in 'review_text' literally says 'no issues'.  This is probably positive, but the algo sees the
# word 'no' and interprets the comment as negative.  I would argue that it's positive.  We'll circle back and resolve 
# this potential issue a little later.
import nltk
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
nltk.download('punkt')


from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df['sentiment'] = df['review_text'].apply(lambda x: sid.polarity_scores(x))
def convert(x):
    if x < 0:
        return "negative"
    elif x > .2:
        return "positive"
    else:
        return "neutral"
df['result'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x:convert(x['compound']))
```

There you go!!  Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for might be a corpus. In Python, there is the Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK). This also has a corpus containing treebanks such as Brown etc. In the corpus folder, there is also textblob and other words/phrases which can be used. You would have to import it though...

```
for nltk.corpus import TextBlob
```

You might want to read on Corpora